# Problem while upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04; upgrade manager seems to be hanged/stuck

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

[image]

The screen shot says it all. I got an automatic upgrade pop up to update the OS to 12.04 from 11.10. It worked fine for an hour or so and for past hour it's stuck at "About 4 minutes remaining" screen.

In the background terminal, the "top" processes are shown.

This question is not answered satisfactorily anywhere as the release is pretty new.
What is the best way to deal with this situation ?

Additional info: I am seeing some of my software programs like remmina, firefox, google-chrome are having some new looks and may be other apps to. Does it mean that, everything has went fine and the box shown in figure is just a spurious message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer. Sometime if a minor problem happens a dialog box related to that will appear and you need to close that. It may hang because of the other reason also.

After waiting for substantial time, if the "Distribution Upgrade" box doesn't progress then click the "Terminal" button at its bottom (as shown in the question).
Press "Enter" keys few times. For me after that the upgrade continued and finally the "restart" prompt appeared.

After restarting, I noticed though that the music din't play and my desktop wallpaper disappeared. They have provided new set of default wallpapers it seems. Don't forget to check the "System Info" to make sure that 12.04 is really installed.

[image]